# Play Push Notification Sound Effect when app is not running (Mac)

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications

I'm adding Push Notifications to my Mac app. The notifications are showing up just fine, but for some reason I can't get the sound effects to play the way I would think they should.

I'm passing in a custom sound to play, "custom.caf" in the apns payload. This works currently for our iOS app. It doesn't play anything when passed into the Mac app. Digging around in the very limited Apple documentation, the PushyMac app shows that you have to play the sound manually based on the userInfo dictionary that comes in for the push. If I play the sound manually while the app is running, I get the sound effect to play.

My problem is when the app is closed and not running. I still get push notifications as expected, but no sounds play. From what I can tell, I'm just screwed. I have other Mac apps that still manage to play sounds when they aren't running. Specifically my email app, Spark. So I know it is possible, but I can't figure out what the secret sauce is to pull it off. Please help!!

Comment: Are you trying to play the custom sound specifically, or any sound while the application is not running? I'm able to get the default sound to play when an application isn't running; I've never tried using a custom sound with APN though...

Comment: I can intercept the notification and play my own sound while running, but ends up playing both. When the app isn't running I just get the default sound. I have other apps that play custom sounds when not running so it should be possible.

Comment: I had few minutes to look into this and was able to get a custom notification sound to play while my app was closed. I haven't had a chance though to investigate what the differences are between my code and Apple's "PushyMac" example, and why one works over the other. Also, what file format is the sound file you are trying and are you using Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: I followed the PushyMac example as best I could. Nothing really stood out other than they play their own sound in -didRecieveRemoteNotification. It wasn't automated. My project is written in Swift. File format is the same as my iOS app, "notification.caf". I even tested the .caf file from PushyMac. No joy.

Comment: The interesting part about the "bogus.caf" sound that's included with the Apple example is that I wasn't able to get that to play while the application was closed (it plays fine while running). When I provided a ".wav" of my own in the bundle resources it plays that without issue when the app isn't running, so maybe give that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. I know the example manually plays a sound when running in the foreground. Mine just plays default sound when closed. I'll tinker with the file a bit and see what happens.

Comment: I've tested a couple different ways. We use Amazon SNS to handle delivery, so I've been able to send them directly that way. I've also used NWPusher to send them as well, both seem to work fine for testing.

Comment: I tried using a standard .wav file, but doesn't play at all. The only sounds I get are the default notification sounds, running or not. Looking at the PushyMac app, they manually play the sounds when they receive remote notifications, but when I do it, it plays 2 sounds. Mine and the default. Push on Mac sucks!

Comment: Well you need to put those sounds in the extension actually. The documentation fails to mention any of that; actually it fails in the entire scope of the what we've discussed. Basically you'll need to include extensions for your app that handle the notifications in the background (eg. action extension, notification extension, today widget). It's ridiculously complicated for what should be a simple task.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. I have to register an extension to play sounds? Any chance you have some code examples or can provide an official answer?

Comment: I'd appreciate it a lot. I've been using Spark mail app for Mac and they play custom sounds for incoming email without any extensions (that I can see anyway). Obviously I don't understand it that well. I have a feeling a well documented answer on this should get you recurring reputation on here for quite a while. ;) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spark does use extensions, plugins, and frameworks which reside in several directories within the bundle. I'm not sure what they all do, although if you look in the resources you'll probably see a familiar `.caf` file.  Just a side note: I'm interested in the bounty you had offered too (it's actually the reason I joined this site years ago - the bounties make it more fun). Anyway, I'll leave that up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to implement the custom sound capability for Apple Push Notifications; the problem is that the documentation does not mention what is required to do this.

The critical component that is required is an extension — (eg. using the **[`Today Extension`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1)**). Creating a new target in your project including the extension, your custom sound(s), and the standard APN functions are all that's required. The ***key*** to getting the custom sounds working though while your application isn't running is simply having the extension (and it's included **[`NotificationCenter.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/notificationcenter)**) present in your application.

**Add New Target > Today Extension:**

[image: today extension]

**Today Extension > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources > Custom Sound:**

[image: build phases]

The only specific APN functions that need to be in your main application are the following:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
                                   NSApplication.shared().
                                   registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: 
                                   [.alert, .sound, .badge])
                                   NSApp.dockTile.badgeLabel = nil
}

func application(_ application: NSApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
}

func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
                                userInfo: [String : Any]) {
}

func application(_ application: NSApplication, 
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
                 print("could not register for notfications: \(error)")
}
```

If you are getting two sounds playing at the same time it's likely that you've got code that is calling `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` and can be removed as the `NotificationCenter.framework` seems to handle all that without adding anything additional.

Comment: So do I need to actually build out the today widget? Is there a trick to shipping the extension without users being able to install the widget in a broken state? I don't really want to build out a full featured widget just to get sounds to play.

Comment: I gave it a try with a today extension, didn't seem to work. Hell, it's not even playing the right sound when I receive the notification in the foreground. I even borrowed the sound file that plays for Spark, so it isn't the file itself. Something is really odd. I may try a share extension which seems easier to hide.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your project looks like or how you have the certificates setup, etc. Feel free to throw a demo project together and I'll look at it. If you have several copies of projects using the same certificates though it's bound not to work correctly. It worked perfect for me when I setup a new app, added the extension, copied the sound file to it, and used just those functions in my answer in the main app.

Comment: I have it all set up right. I'm using NWPusher to send myself notifications via Apple's APNS service.  So I'm getting notifications, but it doesn't want to play any sound other than the default sound. If I leave the sound part off the payload, nothing plays. So obviously it is smart enough to play or not... just not smart enough to use my sound file.

Comment: @BillBurgess: So any progress, or questions? I haven't heard back from you regarding the project.

Comment: I tried getting it to go, but haven't put a ton of time into it yet. Basically have Fridays to work on it, so I'll try again towards the end of the week to see if I can get it going one final time. This still feels like too much work to get sounds to play.